# How to remove all angle brackets and everything inside using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a string of HTML elements,

```
let test = `<figure><img alt="" src="some_image.jpg"><figcaption>I think DC is better than Marvel <span class="whatever">...`
```

I need to remove every single `<...>` so it turns into `test = "I think DC is better than Marvel..."`.

The closest I have gotten is:

```
var str = "<hello> Test </hello>"
str.replace(/<[^>]*/g, ""); //=> "> Test >"
str.replace(/<*>*/g, ""); //=> "hello Test /hello"
```

Not quite, though. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If someone will be looking for answer, I end up using this `str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the HTML as the `innerHTML` of a new element, then extract the `textContent`.

```js
let test = `<figure><img alt="" src="some_image.jpg"><figcaption>I think DC is better than Marvel <span class="whatever">`

const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = test;
const txt = el.textContent;
console.log(txt);
```